# change class from threaded to non-threaded

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tkinter running in a thread, succesfully. I know you shouldn't and so I want to 'convert' my threaded class to a non-threaded version and execute that. I will use root.after (instead of root.mainloop) to try and stop TKinter blocking (which was the original purpose of the thread as I have a While true loop elsewhere in the code).

Can someone point out which bits of the code I need to change to make it non-threaded? 'Normal python classes' are confusing me.

```
class guipart(threading.Thread):
        
   def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()
        
   def closetk():
        GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
        win.destroy()
     
   def run(self):
        while not self.event.is_set():
                               
                global val, w, root, alarm_var
                root = tk.Tk()
                              
                alarm_var = tk.StringVar(root)
                alarm_var.set('Scanning Doors')
                              
                top = Toplevel1 (root)
                redalert_support.init(root, top)
                                               
                #root.after(0, guipart)
                root.mainloop()
                w = None

    guiloop = guipart()
    guiloop.start()
```

Comment: You want to rewrite your code as a non-threding class or do you want to change it somewhere with a diffrent parent?

Comment: rewrite the code as a non-threading class

Comment: What the purpose of the while loop? It will recreate the root window and a toplevel window every time the previous root window is closed, so what is the point of doing this?

Comment: The while loop is elsewhere in the code and listens for network traffic, tkinter displays part of that traffic (alarm messages updating frequently). Had to abandon this, as discovered previously, tkinter blocks and any form of while loop elsewhere in any code will not run as a result, Only choice was to run tkinter in a thread. Not the best code but mostly stable.